# Programmatically edit unix host file

Tags: node.js, unix, dns, localhost

I am currently using a host file to redirect all traffic to certain external host to my machine in order for my (nodejs) application to intercept it.

```
/etc/hosts: 

127.0.0.1 externalhost.com
```

My application receives all traffic that is supposed to go to `externalhost.com` and then decides whether to

a) forward the request to the original resource (e.g. a request to `externalhost.com/target_B`)

b) intercept the request and send back custom response (e.g. a request to `externalhost.com/target_A`)

However, the original resource is the host I defined in my host file, thus, creating an endless loop.

Is there a way to programmatically disable host redirection? I don't want to write to that file each time due to performance reasons.

Comment: does your app read /etc/hosts to find the original resorce?

Comment: No, the original resource is taken from the request itself (`req.host`, `req.originalUrl` etc.)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your setup, perhaps you could posts the relavant parts of `/etc/hosts` and your code. I don't see why you receive requests with destination set to your server, when you only mean to redirect requests targeted at an external server.

Comment: Sure. This is the relevant part of `/etc/hosts`:
127.0.0.1 externalhost.com

I only need to intercept the requests to a certain destination path, let's say "http://externalhost.com/target_A".
To be able to filter for this specific path, my application receives
all traffic that is supposed to go to externalhost.com and then decides whether to
a) forward the request to the original resource (e.g. a request to "http://externalhost.com/target_B")
b) intercept the request and send back custom response (e.g. a request to "http://externalhost.com/target_A")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution in this case would be to try to bypass the `/etc/hosts` file when redirecting the request from your code.

You can try to use the built-in `dns` module to resolve the IP address of the external host, and then use the ip address in the request, instead of the hostname.

```
dns.resolve4('externalhost.com', function (err, res) {
  var ip = res[0];
  console.log('IP address of externalhost: ' + res[0])
  request(ip + "/target_A")
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wont work for my case as accessing the IP provides a different result than accessing the hostname (the hostname seems to point to an individual service on the server). Nice idea, though. Accepting it as it might help others. I guess I will you for a solution where an external server redirects to the original source.

Comment: ok, that's weird. Indeed using the IP can be problematic these days. I'd be curious to see if there's an alternative, if you find one you could add it as an aswer.